# Docker: How to link external folder while building dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to link an external folder, on the host, while building a docker image. I do not want to copy this folder due to its large size, and it is shared over the hosts that run the container.

What is the proper way to do this? I am planning to mount this folder when running the container.

Comment: How large is it actually?  If you depend on it to build the image, and you depend on it to run the image, "the proper way" is to `COPY` it into the image so that it's self-contained.  (There are practical problems if the content gets into the gigabyte+ range, though.)

Comment: over 3GB! and those are datafiles that need to be detected at installation of a package (GEANT4+homebuilt), but are shared on the server the docker is running, so just need to be mounted there

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with the default Docker build engine. But you can do it with Docker buildkit using the new syntax: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md#build-mounts-run---mount

The instructions on how to enable buildkit is on the same page